# Custom android keyboard

Tags: android

I am creating a custom android keyboard. For word spelling correction  and suggestion I am using the android `spellCorrection` framework, but in some Samsung devices `new SpellCheckerSession` method returns null. Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Is there any third party library for auto spelling correction or word suggestion like google keyboard.

Comment: rephrase this question please, so it "is not" asking for "a 3rd party tool" - I don't want it closed but technically it is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Jazzy. and yes its been last updated 2005 but its not a 
big issue because many of use this one and its for English language only when i used now dont know status.

helping link

http://moderntone.blogspot.in/2013/02/tutorial-on-jazzy-spell-checker.html

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, this jazzy spell checker very useful for me.